# Installing newer & supposedly compatible NVIDIA drivers against the 750M in Windows

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

The latest compatible *game-ready* driver for the 750M according to NVIDIA is [`425.31`](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/145874/en-us/). However, I ran across [an article](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/driver-support-for-geforce-750m-gk107m-0fe4/233082) detailing that the `470.xx` driver versions on Linux were compatible with the 750M. And when it's [cross-referenced](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-release-notes-470-57-02/index.html#hardware-software-support) with Windows, the driver version translates to `471.xx`. Notably this seems to be for data center applications rather than gaming, but I'd wager the logic translates. Is there any way to get a driver version newer than `425.31` installed on Windows?

Comment: What you refer as "an article" it's just a forum post by some random user stating they installed a later version and, apparently, it works. The smart thing to do is to use the version Nvidia recommends. If you want to do experiments you're on your own. Abnd, honestly, what are you expecting to find in the latter version that you won't find in the recommended one?

Answer (score 0):

NVIDIA
[GeForce Game Ready Driver 471.11](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/results/176523/)
exists and it's not even the latest, with the release date of
"Tue Jun 22, 2021".
However, it does not relate to the mobile family of drivers.
It supports "GeForce GTX 750 Ti, GeForce GTX 750", but not the 750M card.

The
[NVIDIA Driver Downloads page](https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx)
is correct, and you have the latest version of the driver for
your card,
[425.31](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/145874/en-us/).
As this version dates from 2019.4.11, meaning 5 years ago, it's clear
that NVIDIA is not developing drivers any more for the 750M, so do
not bother searching for a newer driver.

If you want a newer driver, you will have to get a newer graphical card.